# Get Row Index # for Row Containing Value Most Similar to a Value in Another Dataset

Tags: r, matrix, automation, data-manipulation

Suppose I have 2 Matrices m3 and m4:

`m3 <- matrix(6:1,nrow=3,ncol=1)`

```
    [,1]
[1,]   6
[2,]   5
[3,]   4
```

`m4 <- matrix(6:1,nrow=2,ncol=1)`

```
    [,1]
[1,]   6
[2,]   5
```

For each rowvalue in m4 (6 and 5) I want the index row of m3 containing the value most similar to the rowvalue of m4 (by absolute difference).

Therefore, since the values of m4[1,1] = 6 and m4[2,1] = 5, the closest values in m3 by absolute difference are m3[1,1] = 6 (rowindex=1) and m3[2,1] = 5 (rowindex=2)

So, I want matrix m5 to be:

```
    [,1]
[1,]   1
[2,]   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` -

```
sapply(m4, function(x) {
  which.min(abs(x - m3))
}) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 1)

     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

Comment: any way to get the 2nd ... 3rd... n.. lowest value?

Comment: Try this - `sapply(m4, function(x) order(abs(x - m3)))`. In output, columns indicate row number on m4 while values indicate row number on m3. Let me know.